# IE8: window.open is very slow when specifying window features

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have noticed that when I try to use window.open in IE8, along with some features, the window takes a really long time to load.
For example, the following code:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();  
var features = "width=500,height=400";  
window.open("", "", features);  
var endTime = new Date().getTime();  
alert(endTime - startTime);
```

alerts values that vary between 1300 to 2000. If I don't pass the features parameter, it drops to around 300-400, which is acceptable, but I do need to pass the new window size (and probably some other settings). In Chrome, for comparison, the values range is 5-7.

I realize that IE is significantly slower, but is it really that bad? Over a second and a half for opening a new (empty) window seems insane. Is there anything that can be done, or is that just the way it is?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's that just the way it is.. IE8 sucks ;)

Comment: Maybe this is a popup blocker issue?

Comment: Turning off the popup blocker didn't help. I guess IE8 really does suck. That, or it was an intentional feature with the intention to prevent developers from opening too many new windows.

Comment: I have the same problem..Its taking huge time for loading the page when it works in server.Other that Window.open screen everything works fine.Please suggest me the way to make my application faster as like it is working locally.